# Custom Microsoft Teams Connector doesn't communicate with an external service at all

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

**Common description**

First, my goal is sending notifications from my service using an internal API to a MT channel and having an option to answer it transmitting one to internal API.

I've found a Connector has such functionality. Good example which i've tried to use [StackOverflowConnector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAWIN.png). It was a good point to start that is exactly what i need(Bot has inappropriate UI behaviour) , but i've decided to do it by small steps from creating a Bot just to understand things better. In short i had success, the bot and a mt channel communicted well both directions. Next point was Connector. I explored all information here:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/index
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-3.0
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/

**What i have taken to create a Connector**

1. registered a Connector in the Connectors Developer Dashboard with followed fields:

   - Connector name: *connector*
   - Logo: *contoso96x96.png*
   - Short description of your app (10 words or less): *sd*
   - Detailed description of what your Connector does (3-5 sentences): *dd*
   - Company website: *https://external.service*
   - List the events supported by your Connector: *all*
   - Do you want to enable actions on your Connector cards?: *Yes*
   - Actions URL: *https://external.service/api/messages*
   - Does your service support login using subdomain?: *No*
   - Landing page for your users for Inbox: *https://external.service*
   - Landing page for your users for Groups or Teams: *https://external.service*
   - Redirect URLs: *https://external.service/api/messages*
2. Ran the external service to communicate with a Connector. Checked service works
3. took a *manifest.json* file is generated by Connectors Developer Dashboard and uploaded it to a Microsoft Team(MT) team. Uploading was successful. There was no network requests(monitored nginx logs) to the external service
4. selected a channel in MT and clicked the *Connectors* dialog option. Found the created connector in the list *Sideloaded* group and clicked *Configure*. Got such window and clicked Done. Nothing happened

[image]

5. ran nodejs code from the [github connector example][3](it didn't have meaning because of total lack of the requests)

**What i expected:**

Any activity in the external service, other nodes of integration i can't monitor. I compare this failed result with ones of *StackOverflowConnector* and my bot experience, both works as needed.

**Question:**

How to set up the connector to work, to send network requests? At least to have *echo logic*.

**Upd:**

I have noticed a weird report of deleting a MT app of the connector.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is pretty unclear. "Something will happen" is pretty broad.

Comment: Fixed it.......

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have some confusion between a [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview) and a [Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors). Based on your post description you should be looking to [create a Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-create) and not a Connector. Please let us know if you have further queries.

**Update:**

Could you please give a try with [C# sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp) code? Here is the basic flow for your understanding:

1. When user clicks on **Visit Site to install** the [Setup](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/de21d1e6d561c788da1f59a89e1b949187f6bbf0/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Controllers/ConnectorController.cs#L19) endpoint is hit.
2. When user clicks on **Connecto to Office 365** the [Register](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/de21d1e6d561c788da1f59a89e1b949187f6bbf0/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Controllers/TaskController.cs#L43) endpoint is hit with webhook information.
3. When new task is created in your system you can post the message to registered channels using [webhook url](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/de21d1e6d561c788da1f59a89e1b949187f6bbf0/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Controllers/TaskController.cs#L43).