# Why is the Office 365 Connect to office button no longer working with new Microsoft Teams groups?

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

EDIT #2: Looking into this issue further I have found that this feature, FEATURE ID: 26955 [link](http://www.roadmapwatch.com/feature/browse) is in the process of rolling out. I think this might have something to do with my issue. Any help would still be appreciated.

EDIT: I think something must have changed in how the `connect to office365` button works or how grouping is done in teams. I found a strange workaround where if I create a group in Outlook and base my Microsoft teams group off that already created office 365 group, I can successfully connect to that group using my custom connector. But any time I create a team in MS teams, I don't see that team in outlook and then keep receiving the server error when trying to connect.

I created a custom connector last week for MS Teams and connected it to a few of my channels. This week I created a few new test groups and channels and the connector is no longer working. I keep receiving a 500 error from the connect url like the image below.

My old channels from last week still work fine with my sideloaded connector. Any new group and channel I create keeps running into the server error I see below.

Any help at all would be much appreciated. I have also managed to receive this error intermittently from connectors in the store.

Similar to this post from a few days ago, I am also receiving an error when I try to delete the sideloaded app: [Custom Microsoft Teams Connector doesn't communicate with an external service at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724382/custom-microsoft-teams-connector-doesnt-communicate-with-an-external-service-at)

[Error received from Microsoft connect url (Office 365 button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrHSG.png)

Answer (score 0):

@caits also reached out via email on this. Upon further investigation we discovered that this is caused by the fact that the connector code is calling a Graph API that is checking to see if the current user is a *member* of the team but when a user creates a team is created from Teams, that user is made an *owner*. We are changing the joinedTeams API so that it includes owners and members, which should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue when we try to configure connector for newly created team. This issue has been fixed.